# I've been taught that conditions in concurrency do not necessarily need to be written in a loop, against what the oracle doc says

Tags: java, eclipse, concurrency

So basically I am learning a bit more serious concurrency (studying how things actually work, instead of just using random stuff if needed).

And my proffesor, when I asked him about this, said me that he and his colleagues hadn't been able to reproduce a spurious wake up, and believes that line is an old line not deleted (like, it was there, java got "better", it's not longer needed, the line is still there), and that is not the case.

Link:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html

It's right below the point called:

**Implementation Considerations**

In his opinion, a condition that looked kind of like this:

```
lock.lock()
if (p>q) {
    lock.newCondition().await
}
```

Would be perfectly fine, since he says a spurious wake up can not happen, it wouldn't be needed a loop:

```
lock.lock()
while (p>q) {
    lock.newCondition().await
}
```

I am MORE than likely mixing things and understanding both the doc and my teacher the wrong way, but I do have spent some time trying to understand why each thing, and can't come with an "answer" of my own, I either believe one or the other (not like it matters, it's pure I-want-to-learn).

My teacher does spend time telling us how explaining concurrency in java it's pretty silly, but I didn't choose it either, so there's that.

Comment: Right.  So do you believe the guys who created Java, or some professor who tinkers with it in his spare time?

Comment: Well dude that's why I am asking here, to learn. Java has flaws you know? It's not perfect and pure. I am talking about a person with 20+ years teaching concurrency alone, plus his experiences as whatever he did to earn the place. This is not bragging about someone Im not related, I just lack knowledge to know who is right.

Comment: OK, clearly Java has flaws.  But if the makers of it say "spurious wakeups can happen" and someone who didn't make it says "I've never seen one, so therefore they can't happen", it's a no-brainer as to whom you should believe.  I wonder whether your professor also believes that because he's never been hit by a car, he shouldn't teach his children to look both ways before crossing the road.

Answer (score 5):

> Would be perfectly fine, since he says a spurious wake up can not happen, it wouldnt be needed a loop:

Your teacher is wrong for two reasons:

1. Spurious wakeups *do* happen.  It may not happen on the architecture that they tested on but if you don't take it into account, when you move your application to a different piece of hardware or a different OS revision, you will see problems.  It may also be that the spurious interrupts happen occasionally during an exceptional kernel event such as a signal getting delivered at precisely the wrong time.  Again, your application may run fine in testing but when you move it into production with a lot higher load, the frequency of the exceptional event may increase...

   The underlying problem is that certain native thread implementations may choose to wakeup all conditions associated with an application instead of the specific one that was notified.  This is well documented in the javadocs for `Object.wait()`:

   > As in the one argument version, interrupts and spurious wakeups are possible, and this method should always be used in a loop:

   Here's one example of an architecture that has this limitation.  I'll quote from [this interesting blog entry](http://vladimir_prus.blogspot.com/2005/07/spurious-wakeups.html):

   > Internally, wait is implemented as a call to the 'futex' system call. Each blocking system call on Linux returns abruptly when the process receives a signal -- because calling signal handler from kernel call is tricky. What if the signal handler calls some other system function? And a new signal arrives? It's easy to run out of kernel stack for a process. Exactly because each system call can be interrupted, when glibc calls any blocking function, like 'read', it does it in a loop, and if 'read' returns EINTR, calls 'read' again.
2. The `while` loop is also very important to protect against race conditions -- especially in multiple thread producer/consumer models.  If you have multiple threads that are consuming from a queue (for example), a notification that there are items in the queue may wakeup a thread but by the time it is able to get the lock, another thread has already dequeued the item.

   This is well documented on my page here with a sample program that demonstrates the race condition without the use of `while`.

   > [Producer Consumer Thread Race Conditions](http://256stuff.com/gray/docs/misc/producer_consumer_race_conditions/)

In your example, thread A may be waiting in `await()` while another thread B may be waiting to get the `lock()`.  Thread C has the lock and is adding to the queue.

```
// B is here waiting for the lock
lock.lock()
while (p > q) {
    // A is here waiting for the signal
    lock.newCondition().await();
}
// dequeue
lock.unlock();
```

Then if the producer adds something to the queue and calls `signal()` the thread A moves from the `WAIT` state to the `BLOCKED` state to get the lock itself.  But it may be *behind* thread B which is already waiting.  Once the lock is released, thread B dequeues the element, not thread A.  When thread A then gets a chance to dequeue, the queue is empty.  Without the while loop, you can get out-of-bounds exceptions or other problems by trying to dequeue from an empty queue.

See my link for more explicit details of the race.

Comment: +1. Excellent. I've never understood why some people insist on NOT writing a loop around a condition. It's not as if writing `if` is that much shorter than writing `while`.

Comment: +1 @StuartMarks I mean, it is 3 letters less.  Imagine how many letters would be saved.  Less letters == less space!!!

Comment: Ok so I want to explicity say that I am obviously "translating" what my proffesor said, thus it's likely to be not so accurate. I am literally trying my best to express myself.                          So basically what you say (I understood it greatly with the link, thanks for that) is true. But: The case provided by the link, and I think your case too, would be considered (I believe so) bad or not-so-well coded by my proffesor. What I am saying is, can you even code so perfectly to not allow race conditions in a multiple producer-consumer?

Comment: @user2204260 The way you code perfectly is to enclose the test in a `while`.  I know of no other way to do it without jumping through some serious hoops.  The solution would be way, way more complicated as opposed to just retesting the condition.  I'd be happy to have a discussion with your professor about this.  I would ask him/her to provide an example of this perfect code that does not need a `while`.

Comment: Sure thing @user2204260.  My contact form is available here: http://256.com/gray/email/

Answer (score 2):

It is still necessary. Your professor is not necessarily incorrect, but has created a strawman argument to knock down.

There are two reasons why you must protect your conditions in a loop.

- The first is spurious wake-up. Your professor seems to have been unable to reproduce this, and it may likely not be a problem on the platforms he tests on. This does not mean it is unreproduceable on all platforms.
- The second is that between the times that you wake up and actually go to do the logic, the condition may no longer be true. You must guard against this potential race condition. This is also notoriously difficult to reproduce in the lab, and will probably only happen in bizarre circumstances in production.

Comment: The second condition is probably easy to reproduce by introducing random artificial delays?

Comment: @MiserableVariable introducing non-random artificial delays might cause it. Like specifically making a thread spin for a few seconds to simulate a poorly scheduled time-slice could do it for a simple scenario.

Comment: I will ask him about the platforms thing, and the system calling that was mentioned earlier. Also, it is completly possible he over simplified it so we could understand it. He did make clear our code would pass the tests with an if instead of a while, though. About the second thing: as I understand it, we are learning to code in such a way that, if done properly, I do not need to guard against race condition because there won't be any. Because of how we treat the... Problem before the code, I Believe that the condition is unlocked if and only if the condition is still true in that exact moment

Comment: Follow the link in Gray's post. Basically, if two consumers are both trying to operate on the same critical section, one of them will be allowed in first. They are both operating under the assumption that their condition is true. If the first one goes in and makes that condition untrue, the second one is gonna have a bad time - he still thinks the condition is true.

Comment: I took the liberty of modifying Gray's program to add some metrics. I ran it 10,000 times to get a good sample size. Here was the result: the mean number of operations (gets/puts) before a failure 44.5 with a standard deviation of 43.0. The fastest it took for a failure was 11, and the longest it took for a failure was 2731, which in reality isn't ALL that long. Only 33 of the 10,000 were not within 3 standard deviations from the mean, and only 7 of the 10,000 were not within 6. Barely 2% of them took more than 100 operations to fail, and over 75% of them failed in 50 operations or less.